# How do I retrieve the values in html form?

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is just a weak example but say I created a text field and a button in html form like this:

```
<input name="userInput" type="text">
<input value="submit" onclick="test(userInput)" type="submit">
```

and I have this code in javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function test(text){
    alert(text);
}
</script>
```

For some reason, this isn't working. My question is how do I grab the text that the user put in the text field and use it in my javascript code?

Comment: You'll have to give the input fields IDs, then in your handler you can fetch them by ID and get their value.

Comment: The use of this inline HTML event attributes and implicit global variables are both discouraged practices.

Comment: Now I'm curious. Why is this doscouraged? I'm actually kinda not doing this by choice, for some reason I'm having issues getting it to connect to my js file.. and implicit global varuables?

Comment: Also, I chose to write this in javascript purely out of simplicity. I do plan on rewriting this in php but I'm less familiar with that language and i was at work. I just wanted it to work first. This is only a small part of what I'm workingoing on and I'm the only one here who has any idea how to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `value` property of the input element, or your alert will just contain '[object HTMLInputElement]'.

```js
function test(input) {
  alert(input.value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="userInput" type="text">
  <input value="submit" onclick="test(userInput)" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if form contains many values you can 
Use form.serialize method on submit event of form.